# How to use class model as a variable in a function?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, .net-core, model

the problem:
I need to know the datatype of class models which I can use as a variable in a normal function.

the attempt:
I used object as a variable to pass any class Model

```
public object JsonToModel(string JsonModel, object model)
{
    object getModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<model>(JsonModel);
    return getModel;
}
```

the result:
[problem result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDXpL.png)

the usage:
[problem usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dj4GV.png)

```
string UserJson = HttpContext.Session.GetString("SignedInUser");
User UserObj = utilities.JsonToModel(UserJson);
```

Note: User is a class Model

if object makes the problem as it can't stand to use class models as a variable. which data type can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, using generics

```
public T JsonToModel<T>(string json)
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
}
```

using

```
string userJson = HttpContext.Session.GetString("SignedInUser");
User user = utilities.JsonToModel<User>(userJson);
```

I only can't see what you gain using this util, still it is the same one line of code. Maybe if you add some settings if would make sense.

Comment: thank you @Serge it works. the purpose of this is, to make a utility class to do some global functionalities that can be used throughout the entire solution. such as uploading images, sending emails, handling error messages, and serializing and deserializing models

Comment: Of course Mr @Serge I already did so. but I get this message. Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded. If I can vote for you 100 times you deserve it :) thank you.

Comment: @MedoofromEgypt Thank you for trying.  Since it is your first question, I am just teaching you how to use this website a proper way, in order people will try to help you the next time you need it again. You apparently clicked vote up and vote down icons, they look like a small triangles. But there is another icon  below these triangles,  it looks like a check mark " V ". You can click it. Hope it will help.